# Шифрование регистрационных данных пользователя

Tags: java, android

Сейчас дошел до регистрации пользователя и стал вопрос о шифровании данных именно на этапе передачи данных на сервер. Нужно ли шифровать при передаче или вся обработка должна проходить на сервере?

Почитал несколько статей и информации на эту тему очень много всего написано и у всех свое мнение + нужно хорошо разбираться во всех понятиях как и что работает.

Comment: *стандартно* шифруют только пароль. Иначе будет сложно работать с данными пользователя по его идентификатору, которым почти всегда выступает его логин. Шифровать необходимо только пароль(при сохранении в базу). Обычно для этого берут просто какой-нибудь хеш от пароля, и записывают в базу его. Как сказал  @EugeneKrivenja, `HTTPS` шифрования вполне достаточно. Это везде уже реализовано, и руками ничего делать ненадо. Единственная проблема - нужно купить сертификат.

Comment: Вы уже определились, от какого рода атак защищаетесь?

Comment: @metalurgus Я изменил вопрос. Я не уверен, что мы правильно друг друга поняли, мой вопрос именно о том, нужно ли шифровать данные в момент передачи их на сервер или вся обработка проходит на сервере?

Comment: @D-side Я изменил вопрос. Я не уверен, что мы правильно друг друга поняли, мой вопрос именно о том, нужно ли шифровать данные в момент передачи их на сервер или вся обработка проходит на сервере?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko возможно, вы не поняли меня, но я спрашиваю, от чего вы защищаетесь, от этого зависит, чему доверять а чему нет.

Comment: @D-side я вот мало в этом разбираюсь( посоветуйте от чего обычно защищают данные? Я так понимаю, что основное это чтоб их не украли (логин и пароль) и потом не взламывали аккаунты юзеров... или еще что то нужно учесть? У меня просто приложение, ничего серьезного, но стандартные процедуры при передаче данных хотелось бы учесть...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko так вам нужен общий экскурс в безопасность веб-приложений. Это не короткая тема.

Comment: @D-side просто так не получиться передать данные на сервер я так понял? Нужно пройти курс сначала? Вот тут человек посоветовал Можно использовать AES,DES шифрование я так понимаю что перед тем как отправить на сервер данные можно воспользоваться этим? Как считаете?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko зависит от того, от чего защищаетесь. В большинстве случаев хватит HTTPS, но не во всех.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не совсем понятно что хотите шифровать. Если о канале между клиентом и сервером, то `HTTPS` для "обычного юзера" вполне достаточно.

**ADDON**
Вот как создается безопасное соединение с сервером с помощью `HttpsURLConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL("https://...");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Все, теперь канал передачи зашифрован.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39938/discussion-on-answer-by-eugene-krivenja----).